# Exporting data from a js file using react to pass it using props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

A link to the GitHub can be found here if needed
[github.](https://github.com/c0nsy/Clonify/tree/checkpoint-1)

My goal is to take data from a js file (data.js) and then pass it through to other components using React's props concept.

Also important to note that my web app looks like this currently (pink border highlights my nav bar): [current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCVdl.png)
After I uncomment the area in my data.js, the site switches to this: [broken state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj5o1.png)

In theory, I want the icon that is displayed in the broken state to appear in the current (non-broken state). I am just unsure of what I am doing incorrectly here. Any help would be appreciated.

My data.js file looks like this.

```
const data=[
    {
        id:1,
        url:"/public/MainCardImages/hiphopMainCard.png",
        playbutton:"/src/assets/playbutton.png",
        addbutton:"/src/assets/addbutton.png",
        description:"HipHopCard",
        title:"Hip Hop",
    },
    {
        id:2,
        url:"/public/MainCardImages/houseMainCard.png",
        playbutton:"/src/assets/playbutton.png",
        addbutton:"/src/assets/addbutton.png",
        description:"House Card",
        title:"House",
    },
    {
        id:3,
        url:"/public/MainCardImages/popMainCard.png",
        playbutton:"/src/assets/playbutton.png",
        addbutton:"/src/assets/addbutton.png",
        description:"Pop Card",
        title:"Pop",
    },
    {
        id:4,
        logoUrl:"/CloneifyLogos/CloneifyLogo.png",
        logoTitle:"Cloneify",
    },
    // {
    //     id:7,
    //     iconUrl:"/navbarIcons/HomeIcon.png",
    //     iconTitle:"Home",
    // },
];
export default data;
```

App.jsx looks like this

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Header from './components/Header'
import CardContainer from './components/CardContainer'
// import SideCard from './components/SideCard'
import Data from "./data"
import MainCard from './components/MainCard'
function App() {
  const navbarIcons = Data.map(icon =>{
    return(
      <Navbar 
        key={icon.id}
        icon={icon.iconUrl}
        title={icon.iconTitle}
      />
    )
  })
  const mainCards = Data.map(card => {
    return(
      <MainCard 
          image={card.url}
          key={card.id}
          title={card.title}
          playbutton={card.playbutton}
          addbutton={card.addbutton}
      />
    )
  })
  const cloneify = Data.map(logo =>{
    return(
      <Header 
        key={logo.id}
        logo={logo.logoUrl}
        title={logo.logoTitle}
      />
    )
  })
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {navbarIcons}
      {cloneify}
      
      <CardContainer />
      <div className="maincards">
          {mainCards}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

and finally the component im working in, Navbar looks like this

```
function Navbar(props){
    return(
        <div className='navbar'>
            <img src={props.icon} />
            <hr className="navbar-divider"></hr>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

In your data.js file, you should export the array like so

```js
export default [
    {
        id:1,
        url:"/public/MainCardImages/hiphopMainCard.png",
        playbutton:"/src/assets/playbutton.png",
        addbutton:"/src/assets/addbutton.png",
        description:"HipHopCard",
        title:"Hip Hop",
    }
```

Comment: Hi @nver this is not the direction I would like to go. My code runs great up until the area I indicated with commenting out in data.js.
I am wondering why at this point it stops working, and how I can fix it so I can continue using this method.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, the problem might be that the object property iconTitle is only found in the last object of the array in the data.js file. The rest of the objects have title, not iconTitle.